# Visual Studio 2010 Macro problem - Quit Working all together

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros

I built a macro today in VS.. testing as I went, and it worked great.  I proceeded to build another, but accidentally pasted it into EnvironmentVariables Module... I removed it, and saved, but now no Macros that I create work.  I tried the built-in samples, such as insert date, and it worked, but nothing custom works.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: I am having this same problem, no custom macros work - only the samples.  Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 26):

Not to steal anybody's thunder, but I was unable to add comments as I'm apparently considered a person of ill repute, so I'll just add this information as a separate answer.

The page cited in a previous (correct and very helpful) answer by David Coster has since been updated to reflect the fact that it is no longer necessary to uninstall the offending update.  Macros can be re-enabled by changing some config files, as described below:

> **Update (February 18)**: To restore Visual Studio 2010 macros functionality without removing Windows updates, you can add the
>   **AllowDComReflection** configuration setting to **vsmsvr10.exe.config**, **vsaenv10.exe.config** and **devenv.exe.config** files (note, you need to run your editor with admin rights for correct modification of these files):
>
> ```
> <configuration>
>     <runtime>
>         <AllowDComReflection enabled="true"/>
> ```
>
> On a 64-bit Windows machine default paths to these files are:
>
> ```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSA\9.0\VsaEnv\vsmsvr10.exe.config"
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSA\9.0\VsaEnv\vsaenv10.exe.config"
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config"
> ```
>
> Each of these files already has the runtime section, you just need to
>   add the  line.

Visit the [page cited](http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2014/02/13/visual-studio-2010-macros-stop-working-after-february-2014-windows-update/) for full details.

Comment: There has been another update on that page on Feb 25 (http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2014/02/13/visual-studio-2010-macros-stop-working-after-february-2014-windows-update/). The proposed solution for Visual Studio 2010 worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

An update on this: in **Feb 2014** Microsoft released an update that broke macros in Visual Studio products.  After reading the following link I uninstalled `KB2898869` on my Win 7 x64 machine and they are working again.

See [this link](http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2014/02/13/visual-studio-2010-macros-stop-working-after-february-2014-windows-update/) for the full story.

Here is a bit from that link:

> Installing recent February 11, 2014 Windows updates breaks Visual Studio 2010 macros functionality. Macros just don’t run any more without an error message. More specifically, it is MS14-009 update “Vulnerabilities in .NET Framework Could Allow Elevation of Privilege (2916607)” (rated as Important) breaks macros. And more specifically it is the Elevation of Privilege part of this update.

```
            .NET 4.5.1  .NET 4.5    .NET 4
Windows 8.1 KB2898871       
Windows 8   KB2898870   KB2898865   
Windows 7   KB2898869   KB2898864   KB2898855
Windows XP              KB2898855
```

Comment: Oh, and I thought reinstalling windows all day was in vain. Just gotta remove those KBs.

Comment: Crazy, I wonder when/if they will provide an update to KB2898869 that fixes the problem.

Comment: David your answer is awesome. Thank you. This answer must be accepted.

Comment: This explains the problem for every one of us who are facing it this Feb/14. BUT let it be known that it's just for now, the OP had not THIS same problem caused by an update. The older answers keep on being valid for a general situation.

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact same problem.

Turned out to be caused by a syntax error in one of the macros.

Comment: Yeah, that would do it alright.  I think you can assume the OP has already checked that.

Answer (score 7):

To expound upon what @JZumwalt said, Visual Studio / the macro IDE refuses to run **any** macro if there is a syntax error with even **one** of your macros.

The easiest way to track this down is to go to Project -> MyMacros Properties. On the build tab, check the box labeled **Option Strict On by default**. Next, scroll through each of your modules/classes and look for the blue squiggly lines. The vast majority will be harmless like "Option Strict disallows late binding" and "Option Strict disallows implicit conversion from Foo to Bar".

But as your scrolling through, you will now see the one lone syntax error that is preventing you from running your macros.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and the problem was an extra END SUB at the bottom of the entire module--nothing to do with the macro I thought had problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio patch released for restoring Macro functionality:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42541
http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2014/02/13/visual-studio-2010-macros-stop-working-after-february-2014-windows-update/